# HtmlHelper ActionLink omits area (asp.net mvc 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have problem with generation of links
I have an Area named "Administration", it also has a HomeController as a root, 
In the masterpage

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Home", new {area = "Administration"})</li>
```

Also I inherited From Route, and the method GetVirtualPath accepts the parameter values
which omits area key, and passes only controller and action.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem solved, and was in DataTokens. I was defining area only for areas, but not for controllers in the root.
Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? Just started messing with MVC 4 and facing the same issue but could not clearly make out your answer. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You use incorrect overload. You should be using [LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx) (note the last parameter at the end)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Home", new {area = "Administration"}, null)
```

Comment: Thanks archil, but in this case I get the link that points to the same url as the first one... The route is correct if to go manually

Answer (score 1):

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new {area = ""}, null)</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Home", new {area = "Administration"}, null)</li>
```